# Interesting min price problem

Tags: algorithm, math

There are *n* bus stops and we know the fee between i-th and j-th stops.
It's a one-way road. What is the min price of the route from 1-st to n-th stops considering all possible connections? Time and memory consumption should be the least possible.

p.s. To give an example, say, there are 4 stops. We have such a table of prices:

```
. 3$ 5$ 7$
. .  1$ 3$
. .  .  1$
```

to go from 1-st to 4-th with no stops we pay 7$. if we change routes on the second stop we pay 3$+1$ = 4$ to drive to the 3rd stop, but we pay 2$ more if we go to the end, so overall it will cost 6$, but again if we change routes on the 3-rd stop, we would pay 4+1=5$.

Comment: Input data size is of order n^2, so I don't think, there's an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @Henrik Well if there's not that is quite possible, the question is: what is the *optimum* solution?

Comment: Are there routes i->j only for i < j?

Comment: @adamax: Yes, since the problem states it's a one-way road.

Comment: @adamax Right, only such. As I gave in an example table. A dot means no return route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `d[i][j]` be the given prices, and `l[k]` the minimal overall cost to go from `k` to `n`. Then

`l[n] = 0`

`l[k] = min(d[k][i] + l[i], i=k+1..n)`

The running time is O(n^2). (And, as @Henrik pointed out, it's optimal.)

Comment: if you know the minimum price (e.g. 1$) you could abort earlier. I know, it wasn't stated in the problem. Just as an afterthought.

Comment: @Stamp Well, we typically speak about worst case because best case usually doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Dijkstra is O(E + V log V) = O(n^2 + n log n) = O(n^2).  Asymptotically equivalent.

Comment: @wnoise Indeed. I was thinking of the variant with binary heap as a priority queue which is O(E log V). But naive version is O(V^2+E) which is better here. O(E + V log V) requires Fibonaccy heap, AFAIK, which is an overkill.

Comment: I know. Still it represents a realistic optimization for the given problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard weighted directed graph path search.  Dijkstra's algorithm which finds the shortest paths from the source to all other nodes is the best you can do.